# Self-compiled linux kernel can't boot on btrfs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, opensuse

I'm a newcomer for linux kernel development. This is second question about loading self-compiled kernel(current stable version **4.8.6**). The error messages printed during booting are as below:

> linux-05e3 mount[282]: mount:  unknown filesystem type 'btrfs'
>
> linux-05e3 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXXfG.png): Dependency failed for Initrd Boot File System
>
> linux-05e3 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXXfG.png): Dependency failed for Reload Configuration

Actually the file system type of my root partition is '**btrfs**', and it is no problem with kernel version **4.1.12.1-default**.

My partition table is :

[image]

Result of **uname -a** is :

> Linux linux-05e3 4.1.12-1-default #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 29 06:43:42
>   UTC 2015 (e24bad1) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The .config file is just copied from the one used for **4.1.12.1-default**. And I've just ran **make menuconfig** with nothing modified after copying that file.
  Can anyone give some useful tips to me. I really need a linux kernel development expert to give more instructions to me as a beginner. Thanks a million.

Comment: Recheck if btrfs support is enabled (it should be). Also one common gotcha would be if btrfs supported is compiled as a module, original boot sequence used initramfs or initrd with original kernel to load it, and boot sequence for your new kernel doesn't. In that case you need to either make and use initramfs or compile btrfs into the kernel binary. Or maybe you are using initramfs but building it wrong so it doesn't contain required modules.

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave a great answer to me. The btrfs support is indeed compiled as a module. I'll try it again.